# DNN Nav not working in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, dotnetnuke

```
dnn:NAV runat="server" ID="dnnTopNav" 
ProviderName="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" IndicateChildren="True"  
ControlOrientation="Horizontal"
```

The navigation doesnt work, it just displays the items one below the other like a list on the sitemap page.  I have changed the meta following tag, but the issue still exists:

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE9' />
```

[image]

The User agent string field is set to "Default", when I change it to "IE 10", the nav works fine again. Is it possible to set the  User agent string field programatically?

I also tried '40FINGERS_StyleHelper' and used this:

```
<fortyfingers:STYLEHELPER 
    id="SH0" 
    RemoveFromHead="http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible"
    AddToHead="<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE9' />"
    AddAtEnd="False" IfUserAgentString="IE9" doctype="HTML 4.01 Strict"
    runat="server" />
```

That also doesnt solve the issue.

Help please.

Comment: Are your servers up to date with all of the latest patches for the .net framework from Microsoft? They've fixed a lot of issues with IE11 detection.

Comment: Not sure. But is this thw issue in rendering?

Comment: DNN is rendering the wrong thing in IE11, so yes :) [Posts I've seen elsewhere](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/109/threadid/493230/scope/posts) suggest `dnn:nav` does not (and will not) work with IE11, and you should switch to DDR Menu.

Comment: @Olly I already read this but I don't want to upgrade can you give any other solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[Posts I've seen elsewhere](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/109/threadid/493230/scope/posts) suggest `dnn:nav` does not (and will not) work with IE11, and you should switch to DDR Menu.

[Instructions on how to do so are on the DNN Software wiki](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/loc/print/page/ddrmenu-user-guide#How_to_upgrade_a_version_B_DNNMenu_2).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already read this but I don't want to upgrade can you give any other solution to fix this?

Comment: Upgrading is the recommended solution. If you're on a really old version of DNN you are likely going to experience hundreds of improvements by upgrading.

Comment: @ChrisHammond Thanks for your reply. Is there any quick fix at the moment? we could not upgrade as it will take more time and system is very big and we can't right now.

Comment: You can switch to a different menu system as suggested, it doesn't have to be DDR. It could be any other menu for DNN.

Comment: @ChrisHammond Can I use any browser compatibility script for this issue? If you can help then it would be very appreciated.

Comment: I have offered my suggestion, just as Olly has offered his. At this time that is the recommended option for fixing your problem

Comment: @ChrisHammond Thanks for your reply. Okay, Can I add this DDR menu to DNN 5.4.4.2 version? Or do I need to upgrade the DNN to latest version?